# Python: plot panda dataframe of type series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plot, series

I have a dataframe (df) with 10 rows looking like this

```
-2.00    [-24.4907, -24.4594, -24.4321, -24.4012, -24.3...
-1.75    [-23.8154, -23.7849, -23.7601, -23.7326, -23.7...
-1.00    [-23.7131, -23.6954, -23.6767, -23.6616, -23.6...
-0.75    [-22.7675, -22.7505, -22.741, -22.7173, -22.70...
-0.50    [-22.0693, -22.0718, -22.0481, -22.0328, -22.0...
 0.50    [-15.8461, -15.8247, -15.7963, -15.7784, -15.7...
 1.00    [-7.32122, -7.27283, -7.2336, -7.19238, -7.153...
 1.25    [-3.44732, -3.37547, -3.30565, -3.23125, -3.15...
 1.75    [0.541327, 0.568081, 0.597821, 0.627494, 0.667...
 2.50    [3.63716, 3.68494, 3.73379, 3.77966, 3.82584, ...
dtype: object
```

I'm not 100% sure but I think it contains ndarrays, I'll give you the info that I have:

```
type(df)
pandas.core.series.Series

whos
df  Series  -2.00    [-24.4907, -24.4<...>82584, ...\ndtype: object
```

Anyway, I would like to plot all of these arrays in one plot. I'm able to plot one array using

```
plt.plot(df[1])
```

[image: One row plotted]

And since I have a dataframe of type "series" I hoped using

```
df.plot
plt.plot()
```

[image: All rows plotted]

would be the solution but it doesn't plot anything. Do you know what I do wrong?

Comment: Is that a neuron action potential I see?

Comment: Assuming, your data is like what's pointed out in answer, try `pd.DataFrame(df['values'].values.tolist(), index=df['id']).plot(subplots=True)`?

Comment: @JonDeaton haha yeah it is ^^

Comment: @Zero the dataframe I have is a bit different than the one used in the example I think. And I'm not smart enough to transfer your idea to my dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run a for loop and call plt.plot() repeatedly with the data you want. When you come out of the for loop, say plt.show() and all of your plots should be added to the same figure. Here is what worked for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

val_list = [np.array([1,2]), np.array([4,3])]
data = {"id": [1,2],
        "values": val_list
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for i in range(2):
    plt.plot(df.iloc[:, 0], df.iloc[i, 1])
    plt.plot(df.iloc[:, 0], df.iloc[i, 1])
plt.show()
```

The above code added both plots to my figure

Comment: Thanks for your idea! I always try to avoid for-loops though, do you think there's a way to plot it without a for-loop?